# How can I "sendFile" and serve multiple static builds using express.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH**

I want to have an express backend that serves multiple react static builds whilst those builds are sub-domains to a react app home site. With react-router-dom still working to navigate between page components within the individual react app builds.

**CURRENT SITUATION**

I have three apps created using `npx create-react-app ./`. I have one "Home" site that is using `react-router-dom` and then two "portfolio-sites" named "test-1" and "test-2".

Within "Home" I am using a straightforward `<a href="../portfolio-site/test-1">/* */</a>` (notice this is a relative path) for navigating to the "portfolio-sites".

Both "portfolio-sites" contain a basename i.e. `<BrowserRouter basename="portfolio-sites/test1">`

The file structure is as such (note: all builds are the default react builds, nothing personalised by me):

```
./public/home/build/index.html
./public/portfolio-sites/test1/build/index.html
./public/portfolio-sites/test2/build/index.html
./index.js (express.js code)
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I am able to view the "Home" site but when I click on the link to either of the portfolio-sites, nothing comes back. The browser console says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

and

```
 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

**DEPENDENCIES**

- Node version: v16.13.2 (latest lts)
- "express": "^4.17.2" (latest),
- "nodemon": "^2.0.15" (latest),
- "serve-static": "^1.14.2" (latest)

And the react apps are using the latest npx. ("react": "^17.0.2")

**MY EXPRESS.JS FILE (INDEX.JS)**

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// SERVE STATIC BUILDS
app.use("/", serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "public/home/build")));
app.use(
    "/portfolio-sites/test-1",
    serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "public/portfolio-sites/test1/build"))
);
app.use(
    "/portfolio-sites/test-2",
    serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "public/portfolio-sites/test2/build"))
);

// SERVE ROOT ROUTE
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/home/build/index.html"));
});

// SERVE PORTFOLIO SITES' ROUTES
app.get("/portfolio-sites/test-1", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "public/portfolio-sites/test1/build/index.html")
    );
    // res.send("test 1");
});

app.get("/portfolio-sites/test-2", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "public/portfolio-sites/test2/build/index.html")
    );
    // res.send("test 2");
});

// SERVE REACT-ROUTER-DOM HOME ROUTES
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/home/build/index.html"));
});

// LISTEN ON PORT
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}.`));
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED AND WHAT THE ISSUE MIGHT BE**

I've tried adding `"homepage": "./"` to the Home directory's package.json. Maybe adding a "homepage" field to the portfolio-sites' package.json could fix the issue?

I've tried using `express.static` which didn't work so I tried `serveStatic` instead (as you can see above).

If I replace:

```
res.sendFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "public/portfolio-sites/test1/build/index.html")
);
```

with

```
res.send("test 1");
```

and comment out

```
app.use(
    "/portfolio-sites/test-1",
    serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "public/portfolio-sites/test1/build"))
);
```

"test 1" is correctly rendered so the problem must be with:

- how I'm serving the portfolio-sites' static files, or,
- how I'm using "sendFile" within `app.get`, or,
- Within the relative path used within the `<a href="">` inside of my "Home" directory.

I'm quite lost and new to express.js. Any help is much appreciated and I won't forget to give anyone who helps their credit.

Comment: I'm missing the part where you describe what goes wrong. An unexpected 404 response (to which request)? Or an error in the server console? Also, what do you mean by "`express.static` didn't work"?

Comment: My apologises. I've added a section called "The Problem" with the console logs and a description of what happens. Cheers

Comment: Please be more specific than "nothing comes back". That sounds as if there was no response to the browser at all, on other hand, the browser has found a syntax error, so there must have been a response. Anything suspicious about the response's status, its headers or its payload?

Comment: Your error might be in  portfolio files. This code works for me (you can remove the serve static)

Comment: The terminal does not show any errors but the browser does not display the page. The browser console shows the errors I've mentioned and the router correctly goes to either http://localhost:3001/portfolio-sites/test-1/ or http://localhost:3001/portfolio-sites/test-2/ depending on which portfolio-site link I click.

Comment: It works with "send()" but not with "sendFile()". I just want to have an express backend that serves multiple react builds whilst those react builds are sub-domains to a react home site, with react-router-dom still working to navigate between page components within the individual react builds.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have Postman installed but I have never used it, but I have watched tutorial videos on how to use it. What can I do in Postman to get the information you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

- ```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
  ```

You can set up multiple public paths with express. You get this error because the paths that you are passing are not correct.

```
 path.join(__dirname, "public/home/build")
```

this is not a correct way of joining directories. macos and linux uses "/" but windows uses \  That's the reason why we use `path.join`. it should be

```
 path.join(__dirname, "public","home","build")
```

- ```
   Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
  ```

This error means, inside html files, there is a link to manifest. something like this:

> link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

Make sure `manifest.json` exists at correct path.

- Also check all other `link` or `src` inside html file to make sure they are directing to correct path.
- The usage of `serve-static` might not be correct. Instead try with express.static. First set correct paths:

  ```
  const publicPath1 = path.join(__dirname, "public","home","build");
  const publicPath2 = path.join(__dirname, "public","home","build2");
  const publicPath3 = path.join(__dirname, "public","home","build3");
  ```

Then regiester those to app

```
app.use(express.static(publicPath1));
app.use(express.static(publicPath2));
app.use(express.static(publicPath3));
```

simply use with app

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath1, "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: I have corrected the path.join and nothing has changed. The link to the manifest.json file seems to be correct from the `npm run build`.

Comment: and file names are correct?

Comment: I can't see any issues with the file names. I did add a section to my question that shows the file structures. They do all appear to match.

Comment: @srWebDev Instead of npm package, use express.static. Maybe  package's usage is different. I updated the answer with instructioins